# Get data attribute value ... data is returning null

Tags: jquery

I have the following tag:

```
<a href="#" class="Test" data-url="/api/users/unlock">Test</a>
```

And the following JQuery:

```
$('a.Test').click(function (e) {
  alert(e.data); >> This returns null
  jQuery.support.cors = true;
  $.ajax({
    url: e.data('url'),
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      alert(data)
    },
    error: function () {
      alert("Failure!");
    }
  });
```

});

Basically, I am trying to use in the Ajax call the url of data-url.

This is not working and when I try alert(e.data) I get null.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank You!

Comment: e is the click event, not the element. It doesn't have a data attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the data() function, such as:

You need `$(this).data("url");`

And, to note, $(this) will lose scope inside your $.ajax call, so be sure to set a variable outside it and use that instead. i.e.

```
$('a.Test').click(function (e) {
  var url = $(this).data("url");
  jQuery.support.cors = true;
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      alert(data)
    },
    error: function () {
      alert("Failure!");
    }
  });
```

Comment: That worked. So when to use e? Or for what. You say that "e.currentTarget" could be used. Is it better to use $(this) or e.currentTarget. Is it the same?

Comment: It's the same, I'd stick with $(this) as it's a little easier to read what's going on, and thus more maintainable.

Comment: When you say to use "var url = ..." may it would be better to just use "var this = $(this)" and then use "this.data("url")", "this.somethingelse", not?

Comment: That's perfectly viable to do, yep! Just for effeciency though, if you're only using one property, it's best to store just the .data("url") item in the variable rather than the entire $(this) object.

Comment: I see. Just another question. In this case I am using this to verify a user. I don't think I should use GET. Maybe Post? But I am not sending any information. Basically, the url has the id of the user so the user property "Verified" will go from true to false. Do I need to set the contenttype? Should I use get or post or put? Thank You

Comment: You need to be careful here about security of your application, this sort of stuff should be done plainly on server-side without AJAX calls. Even a POST command can be viewed/modified without SSL. Before implementing this, please look into potential security flaws/concerns.

Comment: Yes, I have authentication on the server side. But thank you for the tip.